# Trying to read files in directory, directory just leads to himself and loops in himself

Tags: c

So the code idea is as following: i pick a path in the main, go in it, if i encounter a file, just save its name and modification date in the .txt file, otherwise it should open the directory it just found, get inside and re-do the process for this directory

The rest of the process works quite fine, UNTIL i uncomment the recursive part, where it will proceed to go in itself i think (Path.), then loops to that state (go to Path.., Path... , etc), making the thing completely useless and justan infinite loop

Any ideas?

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

void ecrire(char * s);
void ecrire_add(char * s);
void regarder(char * loc);

int main(void) {
    char localisation[10000]="Path example";
    ecrire("");
    regarder(localisation);
  return(0);
}

void ecrire_add(char * s){
    FILE * fichiertexte;
    fichiertexte = fopen(".\\liste.txt","a");
    fputs(s,fichiertexte);
    fclose(fichiertexte);
}
void ecrire(char * s){
    FILE * fichiertexte;
    fichiertexte = fopen(".\\liste.txt","w");
    fprintf(fichiertexte,s);
    fclose(fichiertexte);
}

void regarder(char * loc){
    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;
    char contenu[100];
    char position[100];
    char modification[20];
    struct stat attrib;
    d = opendir(loc);
    strcpy(position, loc);
    if (d) {
    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
        if((dir->d_name) !="$WinREAgent" && (dir->d_name) !=".." && (dir->d_name) !="." && (dir->d_name) !="\\."){
            strcpy(contenu,dir->d_name);
            strcat(position,"\\");
            strcat(position,contenu);
            stat(position,&attrib);
            strftime(modification, 20, "%H:%M:%S %d-%m-%y", localtime(&(attrib.st_mtime)));
            //where i think the problem starts
            //this is the part i comment to check if the rest is functionnal
            if((S_ISDIR(attrib.st_mode)) && (dir->d_name) !=loc){
                printf("rentre doss %s \n", position);
                regarder(position);
            }
            //where i think it ends
            printf("%s \n", position);
            strcat(position,"\n");
            strcat(position,modification);
            strcat(position,"\n \n");
            ecrire_add(position);
            strcpy(position,loc);
            strcpy(modification,"");
        }
    }
  }
  closedir(d);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
if((dir->d_name) !="$WinREAgent" && (dir->d_name) !=".." && (dir->d_name) !="." && (dir->d_name) !="\\.")
```

In C, comparing strings with `==` or `!=` compares the *addresses* of the two strings, not their contents.  Since string literals are in the program's static data area and `d_name` points either to malloced memory or to a scratch buffer inside the `DIR` object, these comparisons will always be false.  You have to use `strcmp` instead.  Also, the name of the special directory entry `.` is just `.`, not `\.`.  Thus:

```
if (!strcmp(dir->d_name, "$WinREAgent") ||
    !strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") ||
    !strcmp(dir->d_name, ".")) {
    continue;
}
// what you had inside your if statement goes here
```

Note that I flipped the sense of the `if`.  This is just to avoid another level of indentation.

Since you appear to be using Windows, you may want to use `strcasecmp` for the first of these comparisons.  You may also want to use the native Windows API for scanning directories (FindFirstFileW/FindNextFileW) instead of the Unix compatibility layer, for better support for non-ASCII filenames (but it's a big change to make).

I did not check your code for other problems.

Answer (score 3):

`(dir->d_name) !=".."` is *not* a valid way to check if `dir->d_name` is equal to the string `".."`.  You need to use `strcmp(dir->d_name, "..");`

The string literal `".."` refers to a location in memory which contains the 3 bytes `.`, `.`, and `\0`.  It is entirely possible for `dir->d_name` to also contain those same bytes, but since it is in a different place `dir->d_name == ".."` will be false.  But `strcmp(dir->d_name, "..")` will evaluate to zero if the contents of the two locations are the same.

Comment: Explanation: This is doing a pointer comparison of two C strings. While the pointer identify for all string literals like `".."` will likely be the same (because the compiler optimizes them to share the same storage), this isn't true for dynamically generated strings like that of the directory name.